# Conditional Independence and Complicated Probability

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability, independence

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three random variables, which are not degenerated to constants. Assume the measure spaces of $Y$ and $Z$ are the same. Given
$$
Y\perp Z\mid X,
$$
i.e., $Y$ and $Z$ are independent conditional on $X$, is it possible to impose conditions to guarantee (\ref{equ:tar})?
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} (Y = y\mid X = x, Y \leq Z) = \mathbb{P} (Y = y\mid X = x). \tag{1} \label{equ:tar}
\end{equation}

I have made some efforts on derivation.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P} (Y = y\mid Y \leq Z, X = x) &= \frac{\mathbb{P} (Y = y, Z\geq y\mid X = x)}{\mathbb{P} (Y \leq Z\mid X = x)}\\ 
&= \frac{\mathbb{P} (Y = y\mid X = x) \mathbb{P} (Z\geq y\mid X = x)}{\mathbb{P} (Y \leq Z\mid X = x)}.\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
By the similar idea of the comment from @JamieRadcliffe, a naive idea is that $Z$ is a constant and bigger than any value of $Y$, which guarantees the ratio $\frac{\mathbb{P} (Z\geq y\mid X = x) }{\mathbb{P} (Y \leq Z\mid X = x) } = 1$. What if $Z$ does not degenerate to a constant and have the same value ranges as that of $Y$?

Comment: You could consider the case where $Z$ is constant and smaller than any value of $Y$.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe Thank you! In your case, LHS of (1) equals to zero but RHS can be non-zero. Then, I have another question: if Z is not degenerate to a constant and has the same measure space as Y, is there some condition can be imposed to ensure (1)?

Comment: I think that it's tough to find reasonable conditions. The condition $Y\le  Z$ will, in most situations, distort the distribution of $Y$. The examples of $Z$ constant is just to make it stark.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe I can't agree more with you. Thank you very much!